# How to filter and perform group operation for each row on already filtered data table

Tags: r, group-by, data.table, where-clause

I would like to filter data table and perform some calculation for each row of the filtered data table. I know I can do this in 2 steps: 1) filter data table and assign to new object, 2) calculate what i need on the already filtered table.

But is there a way to do this in one step? I.e. a way to use the number of rows of the filtered table in the `by=` parameter?
My sample data:

```
test <- data.frame(min_date = c("2017-08-03", "2017-09-10", "2017-10-03"),
               max_date = c("2017-08-10", "2017-10-12", "2017-11-01"),
               group = c("g1", "g2", "g1"), loc = c("1", "2", "1"))
```

I want to filter only group `g1` and for each record add new rows for each day between min_date and max_date.

Without filtering, I would do:

```
dt <- setDT(test)[ , list(group = group, loc = loc,
                                  min_date = min(as.Date(min_date)),
                                  max_date = max(as.Date(max_date)),
                                  loc = loc,
                                  date = seq(as.Date(min_date),
                                             as.Date(max_date),
                                             by = "day")),
              by = 1:nrow(test)]
```

With filtering, if I know number of rows after filtering:

```
dt <- setDT(test)[group == "g1", list(group = group, loc = loc,
                                  min_date = min(as.Date(min_date)),
                                  max_date = max(as.Date(max_date)),
                                  loc = loc,
                                  date = seq(as.Date(min_date),
                                             as.Date(max_date),
                                             by = "day")),
              by = 1:2]
```

The problem is, I can't use hardcoded number of rows and `nrow(test)` as well as `.N` return number of rows of the original dataset.

What would be the fastest way to do the filtering and then the group by operation? Is filter, assign to new object and perform group by the only (and best) way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe `by = sequence(test[group == "g1", .N])` or `by = test[group == "g1", .I]` or something like that?

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 would this be the recommended way? In this case I would prefer to get some really well performing solution as I have quite a lot of data. Would you recommend this over setting a key first and then using the key in the `by` argument? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure. Haven't actually checked them. Another option would be to use `.N` as a first step and use that later on for your `by`. Maybe something like `test[, nrows := .N, group][group == "g1", blah_blah_blah, by = sequence(nrows[1])]`. "blah_blah_blah" is the calculation you want to do. Should be fast enough, and reasonably readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Moving the three suggestions from the comments to an answer, you can try one of the following (ordered by `nchar`, not by performance, since I don't know the conditions you have to recreate comparable large sample data to test for performance):

```
test[group == "g1", thing_you_want_to_do, test[group == "g1", .I]]
test[group == "g1", thing_you_want_to_do, seq_len(test[group == "g1", .N])]
test[, nrows := .N, group][group == "g1", thing_you_want_to_do, by = seq_len(nrows[1])]
```

Obviously, replace `thing_you_want_to_do` by your actual calculations.

Comment: At the end, I opted for the first approach. In my case, it performs about the same as the second one and it is easier to tweak to my exact case (multiple groups, each consist of values in multiple columns, used within function,...) than the third one. Thank you very much!